# How to make a class public and it's constraint less accessible

Tags: c#, singleton

I have the following 2 classes:

Singleton -> Used to define a Singleton

```
/// <summary>
///     By inheriting from this member you indicate that the implementing class should be implemented as a Singleton.
///     A singleton does mean that only one instance of the Singleton can exists at a time, even when multiple threads
///     are requesting an instance.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type for which to create a singleton.</typeparam>
public class Singleton<T> where T : class
{
    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    ///     A protected constructor to make sure that the compiler doesn't add a default public one.
    ///     A public one would mean that you can create an instance of this class directly which is a violation of the
    ///     Singleton pattern.
    /// </summary>
    protected Singleton()
    {
    }

    #endregion Constructors

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    ///     An instance of the <see typeparam="T" />.
    /// </summary>
    private static T instance;

    private static readonly object instanceLock = new object();

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets an instance of <see typeparam="T" />. When no instance is existing, a new one is created, otherwise the
    ///     already existing
    ///     is returned.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="constructionParameters">The parameters that are needed for the construction of this object.</param>
    /// <returns>An instance of <see typeparam="T" />.</returns>
    public static T GetInstance(params object[] constructionParameters)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsDefined(typeof(SingletonAttribute), false))
        { throw new InvalidOperationException("Still rework this."); }

        if (instance == null)
        {
            lock (instanceLock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = typeof(T).InvokeMember(typeof(T).Name,
                        BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, null,
                        constructionParameters, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) as T;
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Clears the current instance.
    /// </summary>
    public static void ClearInstance()
    {
        instance = null;
    }

    #endregion Properties
}
```

The other class is an initializer that allows me to constructs any object as a Singleton.

```
/// <summary>
///     Provides an easy way to initialize a class as a Singleton.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the class that should be instantiated as a Singleton.</typeparam>
public class SingletonInitializer<T> : Singleton<T> where T : class
{
    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    ///     A private constructor that prevents the compiler from adding a default public one.
    /// </summary>
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    private SingletonInitializer()
    {

    }

    #endregion Constructors

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets an instance of <see typeparam="T" />. When no instance is existing, a new one is created, otherwise the
    ///     already existing
    ///     is returned.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="constructionParameters">The parameters that are needed for the construction of this object.</param>
    /// <returns>An instance of <see typeparam="T" />.</returns>
    public static new T GetInstance(params object[] constructionParameters)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsDefined(typeof(SingletonAttribute), false))
        { throw new InvalidOperationException("Still rework this."); }

        Singleton<T>.GetInstance(constructionParameters);
        return default(T);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

So far, that's not a problem. I'll give you a little example:

My class that I will load as a Singleton:

```
public class Car
{
    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    ///     Creates a new instance of a <see cref="Person" />.
    /// </summary>
    protected Car()
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the name of the <see cref="Person" />.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the age of the <see cref="Person" />.
    /// </summary>
    public int Age { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

The code that allows to change the properties of this class through a Singleton scope.

```
SingletonInitializer<Car>.GetInstance().Name = "Ford";
SingletonInitializer<Car>.GetInstance().Age = 1;
```

So far, everything is working correctly, but in the scenario above, the user can create a class itself and let it inherit from Singleton, just like below:

```
public class Person : Singleton<Person>
{
    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    ///     Creates a new instance of a <see cref="Person" />.
    /// </summary>
    protected Person()
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the firstname of the <see cref="Person" />.
    /// </summary>
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the name of the <see cref="Person" />.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the age of the <see cref="Person" />.
    /// </summary>
    public int Age { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Then the user can call the following code to change the properties of this class through a Singleton scope:

```
Person.GetInstance();
```

I want to avoid that anyone can call GetInstance() on an object, in other words, GetInstance should not be used on any object except for the SingletonInitializer. If possible, I want to detect this at compile time and let Visual Studio generates an error if it encounters such a behaviour.

So, this was a very large question, but I want to make the scope very clear.
Hopefully someone can put me on the right track.

Comment: So you want the user to be unable to inherit your class?

Comment: I've just adapted what I want and it's in the last 10 lines, so could you have a look again please. An indeed, a user may not create a class that inherits from Singleton<T>.

Comment: take a look at sealed classes -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx  or more precisely: **When applied to a class, the sealed modifier prevents other classes from inheriting from it.**

Comment: Thanks, but I already know what a sealed class is. When I make the class sealed, I cannot inherit from in in the assembly neither, which prevents the code: 

public class SingletonInitializer<T> : Singleton<T> where T : class

from compiling.

Comment: I am a little confused. What are you doing in the `SingletonInitializer` class as it's code does nothing that extends the functionality of the base `Singleton`. Can't you use directly the `Singleton` class?

Comment: If you make the constructors `internal` (instead of `protected`), then while 3rd parties can  try to inherit from `SingletonInitializer`, they won't be able to chain the constructors to instantiate it.

Comment: That's correct, but I made add some behaviour in the SingletonInitializer<T> to allow the construction of objects, so therefore I had this question.

Comment: I've modified the code a but (not in this post) but the Singleton<T> contains the core login to construct objects, while the SingletonInitializer now has the logic that will check for the SingletonAttribute on the class. if it isn't present, an exception will be throwed, so now I'm in a situation for which my question is correct. I'll adapt the post right away

Comment: The internal constructor, point me in the right direction, but it would be really awesome if the Singleton<T> is some kind of sealed, but that I have a constraint with the SingletonInitializer<T>. Isn't there some kind of way to make a class sealed, but to allow inheritance for objects in the same assembly?

Comment: @Complexity: No, not directly. There is no `internal-sealed`-like keyword. The best way (as far as I know) is simply to make all the base class constructors `internal`. Once you do this, code outside the assembly cannot create a subclass that compiles. I think this is the generally accepted method of achieving this structure; I've done it with great success. You can make the `Singleton` class `abstract` to boot to ensure that you don't do something boneheaded and manually construct a new instance of that class within the same assembly (i.e. `var mySingleton = new Singleton<Person>();`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either make your class sealed http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx or make the methods internal http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx. The sealed approach is safer.

EDIT: Here is an implementation which will guarantee an application wide one instance per type:

```
    public class SingletonIntializer<T>
{
    public T GetInstance(params object[] @params)
    {
        if (!SingletonContainer.ContainsType(typeof(T)))
        {
            SingletonContainer.CreateInstance(typeof(T), @params);
        }

        return (T)SingletonContainer.GetInstance(typeof(T));
    }
}

internal static class SingletonContainer
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, object> internalContainer = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public static bool ContainsType(Type type)
    {
        return internalContainer.ContainsKey(type);
    }

    public static bool CreateInstance(Type type, object[] @params)
    {   
        if (ContainsType(type))
        {
            return false;
        }

        internalContainer[type] = Activator.CreateInstance(type, @params);
        return true;
    }

    public static object GetInstance(Type type)
    {
        if (!ContainsType(type))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return internalContainer[type];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as mentioned above, making the class sealed is preventing the SingletonInitializer to inherit from Singleton<T>. When I make the methods (GetInstance()) internal, the GetInstance() member cannot be called anymore through the SingletonInitializer() outside the assembly.
It seems that I do have a very complicated situation here.

Comment: Make a static class. Let that class have a static dictionary where the key is Type and the value is Object. When you call the GetInstance method it will check in the dictionary whether it has a key with such type. This way only one instance of the Type person can be created. The whole class can be internal.

Comment: But, if the class is internal, it cannot be inherited by public member SingletonInitializer<T> since than it's less accessible, however, the solution with the internal constructor is sufficient for me.

Comment: I mean to make the static class internal. This way only you will be able to control the global instances.

Comment: I don't get it, I don't have a static class in my approach.

Comment: That is why you have to create one... take a look at my edit. This is pretty close to your code..

Comment: I am glad that we have found a solution for the problem.